# oop operator overloading not returning proper value

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

the following code exits execution.

some thoughts?

I was thinking that t1 is not equal to t2, so i tried to copy byte by byte t1 and t2. But that didn't worked as well.

```
#include<stdio.h>
class test{
    int x;
public:
    test(){ x=1; }
    bool operator==(test &temp);

};

bool test::operator==(test &temp){
    if(*this==temp){
        printf("1");
        return true;
    }
    else{ 
        printf("2"); 
        return false;
    }


}
void main(){
    test t1, t2;
    t1==t2;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
if (*this == temp){
```

calls `operator==` again, so we end up with stack overflow.

Perhaps you meant

```
if (this == &temp){ // &
```

You have to decide what does it mean that the classes are equal. The line above assumes that a class equals just to itself. But if, for example, you define classes as equal if they have the same `x` value, you could write

```
bool test::operator==(test &temp){
if (this->x == temp.x){
    printf("1");
    return true;
}
else{
    printf("2");
    return false;
}
```